# Reactjs Material-Table Select Dropdown not displaying array data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

In my function component I have a Material-table which displays Purchase Orders fine.
On each row I have a Material Select dropdown which is supposed to display a list of Corporations but it doesn't, it is empty.
So I two state arrays...PurchaseOrders and Corporations.
When I use the code as a class component it all works fine.

Screenshot..

[image]
Here is my code...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link, Route, Switch, withRouter, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'
import { TableIcons } from '../Common/TableIcons'
import FinanceService from '../../Services/finance'
import { withStyles, Select, MenuItem, TextField, } from '@material-ui/core'


function PurchaseOrders(props) {


    const [PurchaseOrders, setPurchaseOrders] = useState([])
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [currentPurchaseOrder, setCurrentPurchaseOrder] = useState([])
    const [Corporations, setCorporations] = useState([])
    const [currentPurchaseOrderId, setCurrentPurchaseOrderId] = useState('')
    const [defaultTemplateId, setDefaultTemplateId] = useState('MUR-E-01')
    const [select, setSelect] = useState('none')

    const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
        {
            field: 'PurchaseOrderId',
            title: 'Id',
            cellStyle: {
                width: "5%",
                maxWidth: "5%"
            },
            headerStyle: {
                width: "5%",
                maxWidth: "5%"
            },
            editable: "false",

        },
        {
            field: 'CorporationId',
            title: 'Corporation',
            cellStyle: {
                width: "20%",
                maxWidth: "20%"
            },
            headerStyle: {
                width: "20%",
                maxWidth: "20%"
            },

            render: rowData => rowData.CorporationName,
            editComponent: ({ value, onChange }) => (

            // This IS THE SELECT THAT SHOULD SHOW THE CORPORTAIONS ARRAY
                <Select native value={select}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        onChange(event.target.value);
                    }}
                >
                    {Corporations.map((item) => (
                        <option key={item.CorporationId} value={item.CorporationId}>
                            {item.CorporationName}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </Select>

            ),

        },

       ....more fields etc etc

    ])


    useEffect(() => {

      
// This is the function that loads the Corporations for the Select dropdown ***
        LoadCorporations()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        //  This is the function that loads the Material-Table and works fine. ***
        LoadPuchaseOrders()

    }, [])
   

    const HandleRowAddUpdate = (newData, resolve, createMode) => {       
    // code  removed for demo purposes
    }

    const LoadPuchaseOrders = () => {
      
        setPurchaseOrders([])

        FinanceService.RetrievePurchaseOrders()
            .then((data) => {
                if (data) {
                    if (data !== 'FAIL') {                        
                        setPurchaseOrders(data)                        

                    }
                    return
                }

                setPurchaseOrders([])
            },
                () => {
                    setPurchaseOrders([])
                })
    }


// THIS IS THE FUNCTION TO LOAD THE state Corportaions array
    const LoadCorporations = () => {
       
        setCorporations([])

        FinanceService.RetrieveCorporations()
            .then((data) => {
                if (data) {
                    setCorporations(data)
                    console.log(data, "data") // array data displays in console ok
                }
            }
            )
    }


   const { classes, } = props
    
    return (

        <div className={classes.Container}>

            <div className="MaterialTable" >
                <MaterialTable
                    columns={columns}
                    data={PurchaseOrders}
                    title="Purchase Orders"
                    icons={TableIcons}
                    options={{
                        addRowPosition: 'first',
                        search: true,
                        paging: true,
                        sorting: true,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        tableLayout: "Auto",
                        headerStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold' },
                        maxBodyHeight: "700px",
                        actionsColumnIndex: -1,
                    }
                    }
                    editable={{
                        onRowAdd: (newData) =>
                            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    HandleRowAddUpdate(newData, resolve, "!NEW")
                                }, 1000)
                            }),
                        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    HandleRowAddUpdate(newData, resolve, "")
                                }, 1000)
                            }),

                    }}
                    actions={[
                        rowData => ({                           
                           etc etc...
                        })
                    ]
                    }
                />
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default withStyles(styles)(PurchaseOrders)
```